# How to send json file with 2 different values?

Tags: java, json, spring

I send JSON file (now from postman)
the body is like this:

```
{
    "email": "com@com.com",
    "password": "123456"
}
```

the method on the controller is:

```
public Company getCompanyDetailsByEmailAndPassword(String email, String password) {
        System.out.println("this is email: " +email); // added the sysout to understand what arrived.
        System.out.println("this is password: " +password);
        return companyRepository.findByEmailAndPassword(email, password);
    }
```

I get an error -

```
this is email: {
    "email": "com@com.com",
    "password": "123456"
}

this is password: null
2022-04-04 18:14:07.830 DEBUG 6076 --- [nio-8080-exec-8] org.hibernate.SQL                        : select company0_.id as id1_0_, company0_.email as email2_0_, company0_.name as name3_0_, company0_.password as password4_0_ from companies company0_ where company0_.email=? and (company0_.password is null)
Hibernate: select company0_.id as id1_0_, company0_.email as email2_0_, company0_.name as name3_0_, company0_.password as password4_0_ from companies company0_ where company0_.email=? and (company0_.password is null)
2022-04-04 18:14:07.831 TRACE 6076 --- [nio-8080-exec-8] o.h.type.descriptor.sql.BasicBinder      : binding parameter [1] as [VARCHAR] - [{
```

how to resolve that?

Comment: your password is null

Comment: It appears that your JSON payload is not being parsed

Comment: but I sent the password in the JSON file. I don't understand how to separate the "email" and "password" to 2 different values (How to make Spring refer to it as 2 separate elements, one being the email and one being the password)

Comment: why dont you map the object into a class?

Comment: @JonLin what does that means?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simplest way is to write a simple class

```
public class EmailIdHolder {
  public String email;
  public String password;
  // add setters and getters here
}
```

Change your controller method to:

```
public Company getCompanyDetailsByEmailAndPassword(EmailIdHolder id) {
        System.out.println("this is email: " +id.getEmail); // added the sysout to understand what arrived.
        System.out.println("this is password: " +id.getPassword);
        return companyRepository.findByEmailAndPassword(email, password);
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Since the payload itself is a String (in JSON format), the email parameter is being assigned the entire JSON text.

I'd suggest using a single parameter instead, with a type (maybe named something like "Account") that contains an email field and a password field. Then Spring knows that the two JSON fields belong to a single instance of that class, and you can access the fields of that instance.

https://www.baeldung.com/spring-request-response-body#@requestbody has an example that might be helpful.